# How to go back to an activity and display the most recent fragment

Tags: android, mobile, android-intent, android-activity, fragment

I have found a couple of answers here on SO, but they don't quite solve my problem.

I have 3 activities, A B and C.
A has multiple fragments namely, x,y,z where fragment x is the once that is automatically shown by activity A when it is called.

I go through A.x > A.z > B > C

In C, I have a button with this code.

```
if(flag || rFlag){
    Intent intent = new Intent (getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}else{
    getActivity().finish();
}
```

But doing this takes me back to A.x... I want to be able to go back to A.z.

Is there a way for me the display the LAST ACCESSED fragment, when I click the said button?

Comment: Use onSavedInstanceState method to save your fragment in a bundle and afterwards use the bundle passed in oncreate to restore your fragment

Comment: You can put extra data to intent in C activity and in A activity check if there is your data - you show A.z otherwise A.x. But you in this case should always start A activity from C activity using .startActivity()

Comment: Thanks, I solved it by using an extraFlag and showing my desired screen upon entering the desired activity.